# getting overriden methods using reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I need to get only methods that are overriden in my subclass and not those from parent's class.

For example:

```
class Foo { 
    public void doStuff(){

    }

    public void doStuff2(){

    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    public void doStuff(){

    }
    public void subDoStuff(){

    }
}
```

I want reflections to show only `doStuff()` and `subDoStuff()`. Currently I am using code

```
for (Method m : mClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                m.getName();
        }
```

But it lists all methods.

SOLVED! The code is correct. I just forgot braces, silly bug, that took me an hour to find.

```
if (m.getName().equals("onBackPressed"))  {//<- 
            System.out.println("ethod: " + m.getName());
            return true;
            }//<----
```

Comment: *"I need to get only methods that are overriden in my subclass"*  Why?

Comment: According to the Javadoc of `getDeclaredMethods`: `This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods`. So according to this `getDeclaredMethods` does not return inherited methods. What method are you getting that you don't think you should be getting?

Comment: Yes, why? Also take the time to read the javadoc of java.lang.Class#getDeclaredMethods()

Comment: @Pshemo that is my point. The OP states `I want reflections to show only doStuff() and subDoStuff().` which should be exactly what `getDeclaredMethods` does.

Comment: @RomansStepanovs you should either post your solution as an answer and accept it, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
class.getMethod("myMethod").getDeclaringClass();
```

Comment: This would work for subDoStuff, but the declaring class of doStuff is Foo